# IntelliJ IDEA set up a project for SVN Feature Branch development

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am trying to switch over to Feature Branch style development, wherein work on major new features is done in a branch, and am trying to figure out how to set up IDEA to work with this. Do I create a new project every time I create a new feature branch, or is there some way I should be able to check out the tree from SVN that will let me switch around between branches and the trunk as I work and let me merge back and forth as needed?

I've done several searches, and while I can find documentation on some of the features involved, I can't find anything about how to set up the project to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There may in fact be some third party tools or non-standard configurations to do what you want, but basically `svn` is an "old style" centralised version control system, and you can't easily / quickly switch between branches "in place" as you work.

The traditional svn work flow is to check out your feature branch to a different location on your file system that the trunk / main branch, and to have a separate intellij project for each branch.

Sorry, it's a little "old fashioned" by today's standards, with `git` and the like leading the revolution.

Having said that, it might be possible to set up `git` locally to work with a centralised `svn` repository - I did remember reading something about that a while ago but have not done it myself and so cannot comment if it is viable or not.

Here's a link in any case: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

In the meantime, just get used to alt-tabbing often ;)